# How to copy all the files in certain Directory and recreate the directory structure dynamically using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to move files of certain type from an existing directory structure to a new dynamic directory structure.for e.g: if the file is

```
c://users//desktop//635289512-251.txt
```

I need to place the file in

```
c://users//desktop//635_users//2895_access//635289512-251.txt
```

Should I copy each and everyfile and then paste them in the directory or can I zip them and unzip them dynamically? for now I am using the below code to create the directory. Please help me if there is any better way of doing this.

Thank you for you help.

```
src = "Folder1/Folder2/file1"
dst = "Folder3"+src
dstfolder = os.path.dirname(dst)
if not os.path.exists(dstfolder):
os.makedirs(dstfolder)
shutil.copy(src,dst)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`shutil.copytree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) to copy the entire directory to a new location.

```
import shutil

src = "Folder1/Folder2/file1"
dst = "Folder3"+src
dstfolder = os.path.dirname(dst)
shutil.copytree(src,dstfolder)
```